# Foundation row overlap with row below it

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

Right now I have the following callout row:

```
      <div class="row">
        <div class="large-9 large-offset-2 columns">
          <% flash.each do |type, message| %>
            <div data-alert class="callout <%= type %> text-center radius" data-closable>
              <%= message %>
              <button class="close-button" aria-label="Dismiss alert" type="button" data-close>
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
          <% end %>
        </div>
        </div>
```

When a callout is present, it pushes the content on the page down. I want it to simply overlap, so the callout is on top of the content. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could position the callout absolutely so that it overlaps the rest of the content in its parent.